# Angular UI-Bootstrap Typeahead: Accept top item as selected on ENTER

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

Simple question, but is there a way to have the first item in the dropdown results be the selected item when ENTER is pressed?

An example of this is the user types in "PC0" and sees "PC001" listed as the first option, can we have it use "PC001" on the typeahead-on-select option when ENTER is hit?

I am currently using `typeahead-on-select` to run a function that calls the input via id and grabs the Value for use in the function. It seems to use what was entered into the textbox instead of the selected value, either on ENTER or Click.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="applicationComboBox"
       type="text"
       ng-model="applicationComboBox"
       uib-typeahead="a as a.Value for a in applicationList | filter:$viewValue"
       typeahead-on-select="getApplication()"
       class="form-control">
```

**JS for the** `getApplicationValue()` **looks like this:**

```
$scope.getApplication = function () {
    $scope.ApplicationValue = applicationComboBox.value; 
}
```

*The issue is the applicationComboBox.value is what text the user has typed into the input at the time of the click/enter instead of the clicked/highlighted value respectively. So in previous example "PC0" would be the value instead of "PC001".*

Comment: please show us the code you're using for this.

Comment: I have edited my question to show a simple sample of code that mimics what I am using.

Answer (score 0):

When the user selects/press enter the ng-model `applicationCombox` is is updated automatically. If you want another value `$scope.ApplicationValue` to be updated after the selection, do the following

```
$scope.applicationCombox = ""; //your existing model.
$scope.getApplication = function () {
 $scope.ApplicationValue = $scope.applicationCombox; 
}
```

Let us know.

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what I am looking for. I am looking for a way to grab the selected value instead of what was typed into the select box on the typeahead-on-select or a similar call.

I have tried both the applicationComboBox call and the  document.getElementById('applicationComboBox') to try to get the updated value and they both return the pre-selected value.

Comment: Can you check this plunker and tell me if it's anywhere near to your issue ? https://plnkr.co/edit/TlTmRNSlzMz1hWNuPXV5?p=preview . You seem to have everything correctly setup, except that the usage. @Austin

Comment: Sorry for not updating, but I found a solution that worked for me. I'll post it as a response to the question

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a solution that worked for me.

HTML:

```
<input id="applicationComboBox"
   type="text"
   ng-model="applicationComboBox"
   uib-typeahead="a as a.Value for a in applicationList | filter:$viewValue"
   typeahead-on-select="onApplicationSelect($item, $model, $label, a)"
   class="form-control">
```

JS:

```
$scope.onApplicationSelect = function (item, model, label, application) {
        applicationComboBox.value= item.Value;
    }
```